# Using matlab function block defining system matrix

Tags: matlab, simulink

I used matlab function block to define matrix of its 6*1

[image]

I used below code:

```
function y = matrixX(u)
X11 = u(1);
X21 = u(2);
X31 = u(3);
X41 = u(4);
X51 = u(5);
X61 = u(6);
Xmat = [X11;X21;X31;X41;X51;X61]
y = Xmat
```

But I've got this error :

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'My sys/MATLAB
>   Function' is a one dimensional vector with 6 elements.

I want matlab function get 6 input and its output be [6*1] matrix.

Comment: The error you pasted is not related to the inputs of your Block, it is related to the output. To get 6 individual inputs, you have to write a function with 6 parameters: function y = matrixX(u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6)

Comment: Lacking the relevant information to reproduce and understand the problem, I vote to close it.